Return Cell Location for a list of variables in Excel
I would like to return all cell locations based on a list of values
Example:
Cell A1 has the value of "Rent"
Cell A2 has the value of "Buy"
Cell A3 has the value of "Lease"
I want to search A10:D500 and return the all cell locations for any cell that matches whats in A1:A3
I would expect the results to look something like this:
A results list showing all the cell locations containing any of the values.
A16
D22
C200
B80
I have tried an index and match funtion but it only returns one cell not all

What version of Excel are you using?

It can be a solution:
[C4] =TOROW(MAP(A10:D500;LAMBDA(a;ADDRESS(IF(ISNA(XMATCH(a;$A$1:$A$3));"";ROW(a));COLUMN(a))));2)

Replace the semicolon by the comma if need.

If you need to get the list of addresses in a single cell
=REDUCE("";A10:D15;LAMBDA(b;a;b&IF(OR(a=A1:A3);CELL("address";a)&";";"")))

It's expected to be faster than TEXTJOIN+MAP.

You can use a formula like this adapted to your actual data using MAP and TEXTJOIN functions.
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,MAP(B9:B15,LAMBDA(a,IF(SUM(--(a=G7:G8))>0,CELL("address",a),""))))

